# jQuery CSS Z-Index Change

Tags: jquery, css

I am having a problem getting my photoviewer to change photos when a link is clicked (live site http://ericnaff.com/web2/index-FILL-IN.html). I've looked everywhere for a solution and got nothing. Here's my HTML, then CSS, then my jQuery. I got the links to work but when you re-click, it won't change the image. Example- I click on a link and the photo changes to the right photo. If I try to go back to a photo by clicking, it doesn't work.

```
 <body>

<div id="imageWindow">
    <div class="imagePane firstPic"></div><!-- ends first -->
    <div class="imagePane secondPic"></div><!-- ends second -->
    <div class="imagePane thirdPic"></div><!-- ends third -->
    <div class="imagePane fourthPic"></div><!-- ends fourth -->

    <ul>
        <li class="firstPic">first-pic</li>
        <li class="secondPic">second-pic</li>
        <li class="thirdPic">third-pic</li>
        <li class="fourthPic">fourth-pic</li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

THE CSS

```
    #imageWindow {/* 1 CSS attribute */position:absolute 0px 0px;}

/* common image container and stacking */
    .imagePane {
        /* 4 CSS attributes */
        position:absolute;
        background-image: url(http://www.ericnaff.com/web2/images/park-    
                    sprite.jpg);
        width:450px;
        height:400px;
        }

/* these classes are used to determine the stacking order of the image container divs */
    .front {/* 1 CSS attribute */ z-index:1}
    .behind {/* 1 CSS attribute */ z-index:-1}

/* used to display a different picture in each container */             
    .firstPic {/* 1 CSS attribute */ background-position:0px 0;}
    .secondPic {/* 1 CSS attribute */background-position:450px 0;}
    .thirdPic {/* 1 CSS attribute */background-position:900px 0;}
    .fourthPic {/* 1 CSS attribute */background-position:1350px 0;}


/* used to style the list */
    ul {        
        /* 2 CSS attributes */
        width:75px;
        margin-left:450px;
    }

    li {
        /* 1 CSS attribute */
        list-style-type:none;           
    }

    li:hover {
        /* 2 CSS attributes */
        background-color:#999999;
        cursor:pointer;
    }
```

MY JQUERY-

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('li.firstPic').click(function() {
                $('.firstPic').fadeIn().addClass('front');                  

            });

        $('li.secondPic').click(function() { 
                $('.secondPic').fadeIn().addClass('front');

            });

        $('li.thirdPic').click(function() {
                $('.thirdPic').fadeIn().addClass('front');

            });

        $('li.fourthPic').click(function() {
                $('.fourthPic').fadeIn().addClass('front');

            });

    });
```

Any ideas? I can't change the HTML and have to use the amount of CSS shown. I'm new to this and really confused. I was trying this solution-

```
$('.targetX').functionA('targetS').functionB('targetT');                    
$('tag.targetY').functionA('targetT').functionB('targetS');
```

I don't know how to get it to work though. Like I said, got the first part working, just can't get a link to work more than once.
Thanks for any help/suggestions.

Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's because before add `front` class, the previous `front` is not cleared yet. in your every click blocks add this `$('.front').removeClass('.front');`

but i think i can propose something like this :

```
$('.imagePane').click(function() {
   //get the second class name as the selector of li
   var picSelector = $(this).attr('class').split(" ")[1];

   $('.front').removeClass('front');
   $('li.'+picSelector).addClass('front');
});
```

im sorry i havent tested it yet, but i hope you got the idea..

Comment: Awesome! It worked. I added your $('.front').removeClass('front'); to each item and it worked. Thanks for the help. It was answered above pretty close now that I think about it and what he wrote after getting your solution to work. Thanks to you both!

Comment: So either way then, using z-index wouldn't matter? The reason I have the .addClas is to change the class to front, which has a z-index value. Is it possible to do it that way? By z-index?

Comment: I ask because it does change the class to front, but the others don't change to behind.The front class has a z-index of 1 and .behind has one of -1. Is there a way to get the classes to make the order change? Like the viewable pic has the front class, and the others get the behind class?

Comment: your current approach makes sense IMHO.. assuming the default pic list is -1 of z-index, and focus only to the front pic (which has bigger z-index value). as long as it's only 1 pic that has .front class, it's ok... (and by calling the removeClass('front') before is to make sure of it)

Comment: ah sorry, just check your css. i dont think you need .behind class.. just add z-index: -1 of .behind in .imagePane (this is what i meant by the default z-index, they are all has 'behind' class by default) and we can focus on the .front after that

Comment: Cool! I see. I was wondering if I even needed the .behind because as long as the visible pic gets the .front, it will be the one that's seen. Everything else by default will be behind.

Answer (score 1):

Each link adds a `front` class to its corresponding `<div>`, but doesn't remove any previously added ones.

For example, you can add this function on each click:

```
function resetClasses() {
    $('li').each(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('front');
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li.firstPic').click(function() {
                resetClasses();
                $('.firstPic').fadeIn().addClass('front');                  

            });

    $('li.secondPic').click(function() { 
            resetClasses();
            $('.secondPic').fadeIn().addClass('front');

        });

    $('li.thirdPic').click(function() {
            resetClasses();
            $('.thirdPic').fadeIn().addClass('front');

        });

    $('li.fourthPic').click(function() {
            resetClasses();
            $('.fourthPic').fadeIn().addClass('front');

        });

});
```

Comment: I added the function definition before AND after the doc ready. Now it just doesn't work at all. I see your logic. I just can't get it to work. I get syntax errors in Dreamweaver and it doesn't work live. I get the errors when I add this- function resetClasses() {
    $('li').each(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('front');
    }
}

Comment: I got it to work! After getting the other solution listed to work, I see what you were talking about now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Sorry, missed a closing parenthesis, fixed now

Comment: Thanks for the help! I totally ended up getting it down right.